# How to make Action Bar SearchView text to contain search icon

Tags: android

I'd like to have small search icon in text hint like that:
[image]

but I get it like so:
[image]

I am using:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.work, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);   

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm using `<ToolBar><SearchView/></ToolBar>` in layout independend from menus